# How can I log .Net type information from ?MyObject.GetType in the Immediate window to a text file..?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can I log the same sort of information returned by `?MyObject.GetType` in the Immediate window..? I would like to capture the same information into a String variable or log it to a text file. I think there must be some basic concept about .Net type information that I'm missing.

For instance, in VB .Net, when the code is stopped at a breakpoint, if I type `?MyObject.GetType` in the Immediate window, I get something like the following:

```
{Name = "RibbonUnhandledEventForm" FullName = "WordToAccessAddIn2.RibbonUnhandledEventForm"}
    System.RuntimeType: {Name = "RibbonUnhandledEventForm" FullName = "WordToAccessAddIn2.RibbonUnhandledEventForm"}
    Assembly: {System.Reflection.Assembly}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "WordToAccessAddIn2.RibbonUnhandledEventForm, WordToAccessAddIn2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: 1048577
    BaseType: {Name = "Form" FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Form"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: False
    DeclaringMethod: {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}
    DeclaringType: Nothing
    DefaultBinder: {System.DefaultBinder}
    Etc...
    Etc...
    Etc...
```

But I cannot determine how to capture this same information into a variable or log it directly to a text file. I've tried the following, and none work:

```
Debug.WriteLine(obj)
Debug.WriteLine(obj.GetType)
Debug.WriteLine(obj.GetType.ToString)

Also...

Dim log As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\logfile.txt")
logger.WriteLine(obj)
logger.WriteLine(obj.GetType)
logger.WriteLine(obj.GetType.ToString)
```

What can I do..?

Comment: No, it requires the debugger to be active.  Only copy/paste can do this.

Comment: Buggers. Ok, thanks. I guess I'll have to use the individual `*.GetType.*` properties.